# API design: Should a count() of a set of consecutively-id'ed elements return a size type?

Tags: c++, api-design, count

I'm writing C++ code, where the standard library has an idiomatic type for representing sizes: [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

Now, I'm writing a function which counts certain kinds of objects; and these objects have indices, used as their id's, which start from 0, with some indices in the middle possibly skipped due to device issues - although in practice they are never missing. Say these objects's index type is `idx_t`. Also, to make this question non-trivial, `id_t` is typically different, smaller than than `std::size_t`. It is guaranteed that the number of objects isn't 2^`sizeof(idx_t)`, i.e. there are `idx_t` values to spare.

My "philosophical" design question: Which type should a `count_objects()` function return:

- a `std::size_t`, the standard size type, or
- an `idx_t`, the objects' numeric index type?

Please argue in favor of your choice.

Notes:

- The objects' index type is a constraint, and cannot be altered, e.g. due to interaction with a device driver or third-party library.
- I believe this question isn't really C++ specific, but I wanted to make it less vague, so I didn't generalize much.
- `idx_t` might be `int`, or `unsigned`, or `short`, or `std::int16_t`, or `std::uint16_t`,  or `std::uint32_t`, or or `std::int32_t` etc.

Comment: auto difference = x.count() - y.count() will produce nonsense if idx_t is unsigned. Which makes this a trap to happen when you port the software, or upgrade your compiler.

Comment: so, essentially this is like an ordered list?  Where each ID of an element is it's position within the list?  Conventions are there for a reason.  If you follow convention, you ensure better interoperability and avoid potential issues due to type mismatches, etc.  Particularly outside of your code

Comment: @BerinLoritsch: Basically, yes, like an ordered list, but I don't want to commit to that and make the question ultra-specific. As for conventions - the thing is we have conflicting conventions: In the standard library, `std::size_t` is conventional; in the code for working with these objects, it's never used.

Answer (score 5):

If `idx_t` is an alias for a standard unsigned integral type, consider using it. But `size_t` is a perfectly fine default choice that you shouldn't avoid without reason.

That collections generally define sizes in terms of `size_t` is important for generality: by definition, a memory space can contain no more than `SIZE_MAX` contiguous objects/addresses. This means that `size_t` will always be large enough to report the size of any array of objects – or, for that matter, the size of any single object.

Depending on the context, `size_t` might not be a good choice for representing sizes though. In practice, many collections will be far smaller so that large parts of the representable space will be wasted. A `size_t` might also be larger than the platform's native integral type. With a segmented memory model, we also get the curious effect that `size_t` could be *smaller* than a pointer-size and that collections that are not array-like could contain more than `size_t` elements.

Thus, there are many reasons why you wouldn't want to use `size_t` in specific cases. Leaving aside those reasons that relate to exotic architectures (anything non 64-bit), the main reason to avoid `size_t` would be that it wastes memory. This can matter if you have many objects that contain a `size_t` field, although it will not generally matter for a `size_t` return value that is passed via a fixed-sized register. So whether this matters depends on the wider context of your program.

Indications that you *shouldn't* use `idx_t` include:

- the type is not a primitive integer type
- it is a signed integer type, and there can be more than 2<sup>CHAR_BIT * sizeof(idx_t) - 1</sup> objects in the collection
- weak indication: `idx_t` is equivalent to `char`, since this type is not treated as an integer in some contexts

Comment: Added information to the question about `idx_t`. I did mean to imply it is an alias for a standard integer type - but not necessarily unsigned. Still, its _values_ are  never non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to consider how the `size()` function is used.  It's likely that template functions (such as those in `std::views` objects) may call `size()` and expect it to return an unsigned type.  So returning a possibly-signed type could cause compilation to emit warnings you don't want.

If it's reasonable for your class to act as a standard container, then it's helpful (least surprise) to your users to complete the job - so declare a `size_type` as well as `value_type` in your container.  That also makes changing your mind easier if you discover you've gone down the wrong path!

Personally, I would begin with

```
class MySet
{
public:
    using size_type = std::size();

    size_type count() const noexcept;
};
```

and stick with that unless/until you find some good reason to switch to a smaller type such as `std::make_unsigned_t<idx_t>`.

Comment: Can you give an example of `std::views` code will balk at a `MySet::size_type` which is signed?

Comment: Also, as you may be aware, there is no single return type for `std::size()` - it takes a container and returns its size type.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that we now have `std::ssize()` too...

Comment: No, I don't have an example available, and that kind of failure is more likely from third-party code than from well-reviewed Standard Library code, which really should be using the container's `size_type`.

Answer (score 1):

A variant on @gnasher729's suggestion:

- Insist on signdness of the result type, to allow `x.count() - y.count()` to not produce junk.

  - ... and thus `std::size_t` goes out the window.
  - ... and perhaps `idx_t` too, unless you can rely on its sigendness.
- Stick to being `size_t`-like

And consequently:

```
using ssize_t = std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>;
```

the signed size type we know on Unix systems from `<sys/types.h>`.

Comment: Although you've reached a different conclusion to mine, you've presented reasoning which can help others to make an informed choice, and I've upvoted for that.

Answer (score -1):

I’ll just take a signed 64 bit integer. It’s large enough to count the bits on 10,000 large hard drives. Being signed means the difference of two counts is valid, avoiding stupid bugs with unsigned numbers. I haven’t written 32 but code in years, so I don’t worry about some wasted bits.

Comment: So, you're suggesting rejecting both alternatives I suggested? Why, considering they are both able to count the number of objects?

Comment: So you are downvoting me, not because there's something wrong with my answer, but because I don't agree with you? Seriously?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, so I'm not sure who you were referring to...